# Junit version dependency in androidTest - can't use 4.13

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-jetpack-compose

I am writing androidTest to my app. App uses jetpack compose and hilt for dependency injection. In order to set up tests I need to use order parameter for test rules so I need to use jUnit 4.13 but when I tried to use them I got error when running the test:

```
What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration' :app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.13.2.

 Required by:
     project :app
     project :app > com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3
  > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Constraint path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.12}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 4.12
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2' (releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
> Could not resolve junit:junit:{strictly 4.12}.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Constraint path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.12}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 4.12
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2' (releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
 Required by:
     project :app > androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3
     project :app > androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2
     project :app > androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0
     project :app > androidx.test:runner:1.4.0
  > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Constraint path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.12}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 4.12
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2' (releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'

> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.13.
 Required by:
     project :app > com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1
  > Cannot find a version of 'junit:junit' that satisfies the version constraints:
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Constraint path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'junit:junit:{strictly 4.12}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 4.12
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2' (releaseVariantReleaseRuntimePublication) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
       Dependency path 'Myapp:app:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0' (runtime) --> 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

I copied all my androidTest dependencies from another project where it works so... probably it is something other but I couldn't find a solution.

I found somewhere that I should run a command:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --dependency junit:junit --configuration debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath
```

but to be honest I don't know what I can do wth output:
https://pastebin.com/0F9Wt0mQ

My androidTest dependecies are:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.2"
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.38.1'
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1'
androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.5.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.12.0"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
```

I'm not sure what other information is needed.

Answer (score 4):

For me, adding the following to the module's build.gradle file works just fine:

```
android {
...
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force("junit:junit:4.13.2")
}

dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I found a solution but I'm not sure if it is the correct one.

I've updated the dependencies to alpha version:

```
implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.0-alpha04'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.1-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.1-alpha02'
```

and it started working. Indeed, in chengelog to this dependencies there is junit 4.13.2 mentioned but in project from which I copied the dependencies alpha version wheren't used